# Firefox displaying unwanted symbols in corner

Tags: html, firefox

Hi guys I am working on a website which is going good except I have symbols in the top left corner of the screen when using firefox only.

The symbols look like ï»¿

If i view the .html file that is saved on my computer I don't have any problems.  It only occurs after I have uploaded it to the server, and view the page with Firefox through the internet. Firefox is version 3.5.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you done a search of that symbols in your page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a Unicode byte order indicator.  Some editors automatically add these characters (but don't show them).  Your current editor might have an encoding option that will allow you to disable this (search the menus for Encoding, or look at the Encoding option in the Save As dialog).

Comment: emacs also displays these indicators.